# Sqlite execute vs executemany difference in a for loop

Tags: python, sqlite

I am confused on the difference between .execute and .executemany. Especially when used to INSERT into a table using a for loop. It would appear there is some extra indexing going on but I'm not seeing where

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect("customer.db")
c = con.cursor()

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS quotes(
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            quote TEXT
            )""")

quo = ('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc')

for x in quo:
    c.execute("""INSERT INTO quotes (quote) VALUES (?)""", x)
    print(x)
    

c.execute("""
        SELECT * 
        FROM quotes
        """)
b = c.fetchall()
for _ in b:
    print(_)

con.commit()
con.close()
```

VS

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect("customer.db")
c = con.cursor()

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS quotes(
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            quote TEXT
            )""")

quo = ('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc')

for x in quo:
    c.executemany("INSERT INTO quotes (quote) VALUES (?)", x)
    print(x)

c.execute("""
        SELECT * 
        FROM quotes
        """)
b = c.fetchall()
for _ in b:
    print(_)

con.commit()
con.close()
```

When I use .execute I receive the error "Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 3 supplied.", but when I use .executemany then it results in the following

```
(1, 'a')
(2, 'a')
(3, 'a')
(4, 'b')
(5, 'b')
(6, 'b')
(7, 'c')
(8, 'c')
(9, 'c')
```

Why is does this not result in a table like

```
(1, 'aaa')
(2, 'bbb')
(3, 'ccc')
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `execute()`, you're inserting just one row. `x` needs to be a sequence containing as many elements as placeholders in the query. The query has 1 `?`, so `x` needs to be a sequence of one value. `"xxx"` is a sequence of 3 characters, which is the wrong number. You need to put it in a tuple, then the string will be one value.

```
for x in quo:
    c.execute("""INSERT INTO quotes (quote) VALUES (?)""", (x,))
    print(x)
```

When you use `executemany()`, you don't need the loop at all. The parameter argument should be a 2-dimensional sequence of rows. This means that each element of `quo` should be a tuple, not a single string.

```
quo = (('aaa',), ('bbb',), ('ccc',))

c.executemany("""INSERT INTO quotes (quote) VALUES (?)""", quo)
```